# How to read duplicate string in a text file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want this program to open a text file and find those specific character and add the words after that into the list (each character has specific subitem in the list).
It work well if there is no duplication. But if I have list like:

```
    /* First row of the list */
#Alireza
%Human
&1
@$1200
$*1
*$1000
   /* ' Second row */
#Behzad
%Human
&1
@$1340
$*1
*$1000
   /* ' And third row */
#Samaneh
%Human
&1
@$1570
$*1
*$1230
```

then it only add the first row. I also make a while loop but it will only add first row to other rows. Is there anyone can help please!(by the way my list include 6 columns )

this is the code:

```
   Public code As String
   Public cat As String
   Public stock As Integer
   Public price As Double
   Public sold As Double
   Public cost As Double
   Public i As Integer

Public Sub _Load(ByVal FileName As String)

    Dim strLines() As String
    Dim strLine As String


    Dim strData As String
    Dim objFileInfo As New FileInfo(FileName)

    strData = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(FileName)

    strLines = strData.Split(New String() {ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        For Each strLine In strLines
            If strLine.StartsWith("#") Then
                code = strLine.Substring(1)

            End If
            strLine = Nothing
        Next

        For Each strLine In strLines
            If strLine.StartsWith("%") Then
                cat = strLine.Substring(1)
                Exit For
            End If
            strLine = Nothing
        Next

        For Each strLine In strLines
            If strLine.StartsWith("&") Then
                stock = strLine.Substring(1)
                Exit For
            End If
            strLine = Nothing
        Next

        For Each strLine In strLines
            If strLine.StartsWith("@$") Then
                price = strLine.Substring(2)
                Exit For
            End If
            strLine = Nothing
        Next

        For Each strLine In strLines
            If strLine.StartsWith("$*") Then
                sold = strLine.Substring(2)
                Exit For
            End If
            strLine = Nothing
        Next

        For Each strLine In strLines
            If strLine.StartsWith("*$") Then
                cost = strLine.Substring(2)
                Exit For
            End If
            strLine = Nothing
        Next
End Sub


Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles toolImport.Click
    Dim ans As String



    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "What are you looking for?"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|Data Files (*.dat)|*.dat|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "myList"
    Try
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

            Do While sr.Peek > -1
                _Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
                Dim list As New ListViewItem(code)
                list.SubItems.Add(cat)
                list.SubItems.Add(stock)
                list.SubItems.Add(price)
                list.SubItems.Add(sold)
                list.SubItems.Add(cost)
                listClothes.Items.Add(list)
                i += 1
                MessageBox.Show("Your list has been uploaded successfully", "ccc!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Loop

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the 6 columns (lines in the input file) always in the same order?

Comment: Also, in your button1_Click, where do `sr` and `i` come from?  I don't see them defined anywhere in your code snippet that you posted.

Comment: Yes. When user save the file they are in same order as I wrote here!

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: For i is as public but for sr I've just edited the code again! it is as new streamreader. This is WinForms

Comment: I have an answer for you (and a possible solution) - give me about 20 minutes to write it up.

Comment: Sure. Thanks in advance! I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "duplicate strings", I think you mean how to read the file when there is more than one item (group of 6 columns) in the file.

The reason your current program is getting only the first item is because you're exiting the `For` loop after you find the first occurrence of a given sub item, regardless of how many there may be in the file.

One way to resolve this is to change your sub `_Load` to a function and have it return a `List(Of ListViewItem)` object, which you could then iterate through and add to the master list (`ListClothes`).  I would also get rid of the `StreamReader`, as you don't need it for what you are doing.  You're passing the `FileName` property (which contains the path and extensions) from the `OpenFileDialog`, so you can simply use that in the `_Load` function.

It would look something like this:

```
Public Function _Load(ByVal FileName As String) As List(Of ListViewItem)

    Dim Lines() As String
    Dim List(Of ListViewItem) StockList = New List(Of ListViewItem)
    Dim ListViewItem As StockItem    

    Lines = File.ReadAllText(FileName).Split(New String() _
                 { ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    For j = 0 To Lines.Length - 1 Step 6    

        StockItem = New ListViewItem(Lines(j))
        StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 1))
        StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(J + 2))
        StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 3))
        StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(J + 4))
        StockItem.SubItems.Add(Lines(j + 5))  

        StockList.Add(StockItem)
    Next

    Return StockList
End Function
```

The above code takes the passed in `FileName`, does a split on the string returned from `ReadAllText` and removes empty entries.

Next it loops through code, 6 lines at a time. In the loop a new ListViewItem is created, and the sub items are populated, and then this ListViewItem is added to the `List(Of ListViewItem)`.

The populated `StockList` is then returned.

In your `button1_Click` event, you could use it like this:

```
Private Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles toolImport.Click

    Dim ans As String
    Dim stockItems As List(Of ListViewItem)

    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "What are you looking for?"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|Data Files (*.dat)|*.dat|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "myList"

    Try
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            stockItems = _Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

            For Each (stockItem As ListViewItem in stockItems)
                listClothes.Add(stockItem)
            Next

            MessageBox.Show("Your list has been uploaded successfully", "ccc!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
         End If
     Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
     End Try
End Sub
```

In this code, you pass the selected `FileName` to the `_Load` method and assign its return value to the local `stockItems` variable.

Then you loop through the `stockItems` list, and add each `ListViewItem` in it to your `clothesList`.

**NOTE** that this code is brittle - if the columns are not in the correct order in the input file, or if a column(s) is/are missing, your data will be skewed, and the program could potentially crash if you try to read a line in the array (from the file) that doesn't exist.  Of course, you can wrap that code in a Try Catch block as well.

This is merely one way to do it - I have no doubt there are others.  But this should at least get you going in the right direction.

**EDIT**
The easiest way to remove the leading characters is to add them to the split, like this:

```
Lines = File.ReadAllText(FileName).Split(New String() _
             { ControlChars.CrLf, "#", "%", "&", "@$", "$*", "*$"}, _
              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This will return an array of all the lines, minus empty lines and the leading characters.

Of course, with the code above, you actually don't need those leading characters anymore, as long as the input file always has the columns in the same order.

Comment: I tried your code is work as I want but I don't want to add those character like "#", "%" and etc to the list! Do you know any advice ?

Comment: @EmPlusPlus - Yep.  I'll update my example in a bit to remove those characters.