# remove lines that has duplicated words in begining before comma

Tags: vb.net, csv, notepad++

Welcome ,

here's the text file

> Soma, ID 6588, 1988
>
> Lara, ID 4652, 1995
>
> John, ID 1098, 1987
>
> Soma, ID 7898, 1998
>
> John, ID 1024, 1996

i want to delete any line that starts with a duplicated word before the first comma .

so the text will be :

> Soma, ID 6588, 1988
>
> Lara, ID 4652, 1995
>
> John, ID 1024, 1996

the order is not necessary.

any ideas ?

using : notepad++ , vb.net .

Comment: Any example of duplicate word you're talking about plz?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK like Soma,John . they are duplicated in different lines .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of VB.net, regular expression can do this.

1. Open your text file with notepad++
2. Show Replace window by pressing CTRL+H
3. In "Find what", input `(^[^,]+).+\r\n((.|\r\n)+)\1`
4. In "Replace with", input `\2\1`
5. In "Search Mode", choose "Regular expression"
6. Click "Replace All" button a few times until 0 occurrence was replaced
7. You got what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding each row to a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use the part before the comma as the key, and the rest of the line as the data. Then you can check each time you add a new line with the `.ContainsKey` method to see if the line already exists. A tutorial is [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-vbnet).

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this site:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/503-how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-with-regular-expressions/

[How to read duplicate string in a text file in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051383/how-to-read-duplicate-string-in-a-text-file-in-vb-net)